# Rails: Find record by created_at beginning_of_week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to find a record by created_at: beginning_of_week?
Something like:

```
Message.find_by(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_week).
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: That code *does* work - it does exactly what you're telling it: Find a record that was created *exactly* at the beginning of the week!! But I'm guessing this is not what you want to do, which is why you're here... So can you please be a little more specific in what you want to achieve?

Comment: For example, I suspect what you're actually trying to do is something like: "Find *all* records created *this week*" (I.e. Where `created_at >= Date.today.beginning_of_week`). Or maybe you want to find the *first* record created this week? Or maybe all records created on the *first day* of this week? Or maybe the last record created *last week*? I don't know what you want exactly, which is why I'm asking for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `created_at` is a `DateTime` object which includes both a Date and Time value, then your

```
Message.find_by(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_week)
# Message Load (6.2ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE "messages"."created_at" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["created_at", "2018-01-29"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

... will try to find a record at exactly `2018-01-29 00:00:00` which is a Message record that is exactly created at midnight, instead of `2018-01-29` that you might have expected. You do not want that and instead want ANY record that is created in that day (as far as I understood your question). So, you can try the following instead.

```
date_beginning_this_week = Date.today.beginning_of_week
Message.where(created_at: date_beginning_this_week..(date_beginning_this_week + 1.day))
# Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "messages".* FROM "messages" WHERE ("messages"."created_at" BETWEEN $1 AND $2) LIMIT $3  [["created_at", "2018-01-29"], ["created_at", "2018-01-30"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```